# Check if a variable is convertible to a string in Hacklang

Tags: hacklang

I have a Hacklang generic class like this:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    public function __construct(private T $input) {

    }

    public function __toString() : string {
        return (string)$this->input;
    }
}
```

I do not want to limit the variable that can be used as `<T>`, but I do want it to be convertible to a string.

**Is there a way in Hacklang to specify a given variable should be bool, int, float, string or an object with __toString?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a fair bit of digging, there is no solution to this in Hacklang at the moment. The only thing you have is `\Stringish`, an undocumented interface that covers both native strings and objects with the `__toString` method. It does not, however, cover `int`, `float` or `bool`.

Source: [interfaces.hhi](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/hphp/hack/hhi/interfaces.hhi)

Comment: My day is ruined.

Comment: @bishop I've submitted a ticket here: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/7566
We'll see how it goes.